# Will Pokémon GO work on the Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime?

Tags: pokemon-go, android

Does Pokémon GO work on the Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime without crashing?

Answer (score 2):

Pokemon Go will work [if you have](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221958248-Supported-devices):

- Android 4.4 to Android 6.0.1
- Strong internet connection (Wi-Fi, 3G, or 4G)
- GPS and Location Services

GSMArena shows that the Galaxy Grand Prime[2](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_grand_prime-6708.php) meets these requirements and so I think you'll have no problem with it.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Galaxy Grand Prime and yes, it works.
And for the crash ... well I think the game crashes on most any smartphone out there more or less.